# what belongs in a first university-level geometry course?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, teaching

I know this is not really a research question, but I would like to ask it of research mathematicians, to see if there is a consensus. In a recent discussion on this topic, someone suggested that if you ask 10 different mathematicians you'll get 10 different answers ...

My question: What topics do people think should be taught in a first course in Geometry at undergraduate level? You can assume students have already covered basic Linear Algebra and  Analysis. The course would be of 10-12 weeks, with 2 lectures per week (typical course length in the UK).

In contrast to say Analysis or Algebra, it seems not obvious to me at all.  In Algebra I don't think I'd be sticking my neck out to suggest one would introduce groups, subgroups, cosets, Lagrange's theorem, normal subgroups, factor groups - the syllabus writes itself.  In Analysis it would be convergence (sequences and possibly series) and continuity. (If you want to disagree with those suggestions, please start a different thread.)

Comment: "Geometry" is extremely broad and there are dozens of vastly different areas it could refer to. Euclidean (synthetic) geometry? Analytic geometry? Intro to differential geometry?

Comment: You might post at [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), which is a better home for your question.

Comment: i guess one idea is to follow the first couple of topics covered in highly cited textbooks eg. Petersen's "Riemannian Geometry" book. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-26654-1.pdf

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks.  This is my point: do people have definite ideas of what should be taught first or not? And how much does this vary amongst those that do, But it's been closed - too bad! Perhaps I should try Joseph O'Rourke's suggestion.

Comment: I think your best bet might be to ask someone *at your department* to know what the expectations are for what is to be covered in the course.